# setProperty with exceptions

Tags: groovy

I understand that you can override the `setProperty` method in a Groovy class to intercept the setter logic. However, sometimes you want to intercept most of the setter logics in a certain way but for a few cases you want to have a special logic.

For example, suppose we have a class like below:

```
class PropertyDemo {
    @Override
    void setProperty( String property, Object value ) {
        println "Setting ${property} to ${value.toString()}"
    }

    void setFoo( String whatever ) {
        println 'Foo'
    }

    void setBar( String whatever ) {
        println 'Bar'
    }

    static void main( String[] args ) {
        PropertyDemo demo = new PropertyDemo()
        demo.baz = 'baz'
        demo.foo = 'baz'
        demo.bar = 'baz'
    }
}
```

The output of the `main` call is like below:

```
Setting baz to baz
Setting foo to baz
Setting bar to baz
```

As you can see, the special `setFoo` and `setBar` setters are not even used. Granted, you can call them explicitly if you need to. You can also add something like

```
if( property == 'foo' ) setFoo( value )
```

in the beginning of `setProperty` to use the dot accessor syntax. But this seems a little ugly to me. So, is there an out-of-box support in Groovy to add exceptional properties to `setProperty`, i.e., make `setFoo` and `setBar` exceptions for `setProperty` in the case above?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's corrected code:

```
@Override
void setProperty(String property, Object value) {
    def metaProperty = this.metaClass.getMetaProperty(property)
    if(metaProperty) metaProperty.setProperty(this, value)
    else println "Setting ${property} to ${value.toString()}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set only if the property is missing using `propertyMissing`:

```
class PropertyDemo {

  def state

  void propertyMissing( String property, Object value ) {
      state = "Setting ${property} to ${value.toString()}"
  }

  void setFoo( String whatever ) {
      state = 'Foo'
  }

  void setBar( String whatever ) {
      state = 'Bar'
  }
}

def demo = new PropertyDemo()

demo.with {
  baz = 'baz'
  assert state == 'Setting baz to baz'

  foo = 'baz'
  assert state == 'Foo'

  bar = 'baz'
  assert state == 'Bar'
}
```